# How to know how many files a process opened efficiently?

Tags: linux, files, lsof

I knows I can use the command

```
lsof -p xxxx | wc -l
```

to know the count of opened files op a process, it works, but however, it is just too inefficient.  I have some server process which have too many socket files, the wc -l method never return the result.  So, what is the efficient way to know how many files opened on a process?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is a proc interface for open files: /proc/PID/fd/.  It is a directory of symlinks.  Any open sockets will appear to be linked to a file named "socket:[INODE NUMBER]"

Answer (score 0):

Use `ps -C <progname> -o pid= | wc -l` where *progname* is the name of the process in a `ps`-listing.

Comment: That gives a count of processes not the count of open files.

Comment: Sorry, my explanation wasn't specific enough. As described by Andrew E. Falcon, these are file descriptor PIDs. You can see which file is behind a PID by running it that way:

`for pid in $(ps -C <progname> -o pid=); do ls -l /proc/$pid/fd; done`

Answer (score 0):

Some context (use-case scenarios) may provide better direction for answers.

Documentation of *lsof* describes a few methods that it calls that may block for undesirable amounts of time.  I would suggest glancing over the *BLOCKS AND TIMEOUTS* section of the *lsof* man page.

You might try the following and see if it provides desirable results:

```
lsof -bwp $pid | wc -l
```